# making a Like Query with multiple variables.please help me to make a query shorter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

**thats my SQL Query**

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("select * from fistevent WHERE  row_name LIKE 'A%' And Event_Id =? OR row_name LIKE 'B%' And Event_Id =? OR row_name LIKE 'C%' And Event_Id =? OR row_name LIKE 'D%' And Event_Id =? OR row_name LIKE 'E%' And Event_Id =? order by row_name ASC");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['EventId']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

**How to compare values from database with array comes from html  in my code**

```
$TicketType =$_POST['Tickettype'];
$seatS=$_POST['finalSeats'];
$EventId=$_POST["Eventid"];
$sqlData = array();
```

**getting results from database**

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM fist WHERE `Id`=? AND `Type`=?") or die($con->error);
```

**binding the results**

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$EventId , $TicketType);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt-> bind_result($id,$Event_Id,$TicketType,$seats);
if($stmt->fetch())
{
$data[] = array($id,$Event_Id,$TicketType,$seats);
$Tickettype=$TicketType;
$Rowname=$row_name;
$Seats=$seats;
$cats = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $seatS)));
foreach($cats as $key => $cat ) {
```

**Here i want to compare $cat with database values $Seats But**

```
while($Seats==$cat)
{
echo "already hold";
}
else
{
echo "hold the seats";
}
}
}
```

Comment: You can pass the character or string you want to search so that you can use only one LIKE function

Comment: Can you please edit my code sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have the same event_id so you could use a query like

```
select * from fistevent WHERE (row_name LIKE 'A%' OR row_name LIKE 'B%' OR row_name LIKE 'C%' OR row_name LIKE 'D%' OR row_name LIKE 'E%') And Event_Id =? order by row_name ASC
```

Comment: sir its working. can You please tell one thing .how can i use Alfabets in front of every row in it ..Like A To E

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use a range like that in a query

Comment: sir can you tell me please how can i compare the values in my code